# How can I find (generate) data points form a shape in 2D in MATLAB ? For example, the letter A , B ,and C. Thanks

Tags: shapes

How can I find or generate data points form a shape in 2D in MATLAB ? For example, the letters A, B, and C.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fill()

An example for an octogon, provided by
See https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fill.html

```
% Generate the points required for the fill.
t = (1/16:1/8:1)'*2*pi; % using 1/8 steps we get an 8 sided object.
x = cos(t);
y = sin(t);
% fill the data
fill(x,y,'r')
axis square % prevent skewing the result.
```

An example of generating the x y coordinates of a rectangle with an offset of (5,5):

```
x=[5 5 25 25 5]
y=[5 15 15 5 5]
```

You have 5 points because you need to include the final point to complete the path ( I believe ) Follow the blue path when collecting the x coordinates and the y coordinates. You can see we start at 5,5 then move to 5,15 --- so the first part of the path is

```
x=[5 5 ...
y=[5 15 ...
```

[image: Grid Depiction of Rectangle]

If you want to generate the coordinates automatically, you could use a program like InkScape (vector program) to help you convert a character to paths, but here is a simple example drawn with the pen tool:
The points are given by

```
m 0,1052.3622 5,-10 5,0 5,10 z
```

which 1052.3622 is VERY large, but is ultimately because I placed my shape at the bottom of the page. if we set this to be 0,0 it would go to the top of the page.

[image: Inkscape Example]

Comment: Dear Cody G, Thank you very much for this answer. Please, I am looking for the data points that are form a figure or shape like letter A, B, and C. Thanks

Comment: Draw out A, B, C on a grid and then generate the x,y coordinates in an array and then draw a path. Another example would be a square where `x=[1 1 2 2]; y=[1 2 1 2]`  You can look for pre-made vector coordinates, or you can simply make your own as I have stated.

Comment: You might be able to generate coodrinates of a character path using a program like InkScape

Comment: Hi Cody G, thank you for answer. I am so sorry to buther you, but I am new in MATLAB. How can I draw out Letter A, B, C on a grid and generate x,y coordinates and draw the path.

Comment: I won't do A,B,C for you --- the point of this site is not to program for you, but answer questions to help you over difficult parts. Do you know how to generate the X Y coordinates of a square path?

Comment: Hi Cody G, thank you very much. I do apologies for lack of my information about MATLAB. As i said I am new in MATLAB and programming in general. For your question, in fact I do not know how to generate the X Y coordinates of a square path.

Comment: OK let me make you a better example.

Comment: Yes please, move to chat

Comment: Yes. it is clear now how to make a vector for the border of a shape. Now, how we can find the data points that fill the shape if we use the function Plot ?

Comment: instead of plot(x,y) use fill(x,y) ? You already have the data points given by `x=[ 5 5...]` and `y=[5 15...` these are `(x5,y5)` and `(x5,y15)`

Comment: Thank you very very much. Really it is very useful. Please, just have one more question, if I would like to find the data points that fill the shape without use fill() function, how can I do that. Thanks

Comment: fill() doesn't help you find data points, it generates the 2D shape on a XY graph. --- you have to generate them by hand/manually (what we've done) or use inkscape (complicated) or generate some algorithm of your own to get them (very complicated)

Comment: Hi Cody G, I just want to tell you that I install the Inkscape program for drawing but I could not find how to get the coordinates of each shape. Please, could you tell me how can I find the coordinates of any shape that I draw. Thanks.

Comment: If you draw with the pen tool then just look at the path's object properties in the dialog window on the right of the screen. See updated example in my answer.

Comment: Dear Cody G, thank you for this updated figure, but I cannot find the dialog window you mentioned. I do not now how to add this dialog, please, could you help.

Comment: I took picture for my screen, how can I send it to you ! Ctl+v does not work on comments !

Comment: Use ctrl+shift+X to open the "XML dialog"

Comment: Hi Cody G. I opened XML Editor, but how can I see the coordinates of a shape ? the x and y in the down right corner are not useful !

Comment: The x and y are useful. They are listed as M X1,Y1 X2,Y2 X3,Y3 X4,Y4 Z.